# how to use a class defined under java class library of net beans in another class of different package

Tags: java, javabeans

```
public class NewClass {
  private double depth;
  public NewClass(){}
  public double getDepth() {
      return depth;
  }
 public void setDepth(double d){
     depth = d;
 }
}
```

The above code was defined under JavaLibrary3 in netbeans. how can I access setDepth() from main() of other program

Comment: Make sure you use import the class JavaLibrary3.NewClass.

Answer (score 0):

using

```
new NewClass().setDepth(doubleValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting and getting the *depth* is easy. You simply have to create an object, as required.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NewClass nc = new NewClass();
    nc.setDepth(3.45);
    System.out.println("The depth is " + nc.getDepth());
}
```

I hope you do understand what object-oriented programming (OOP) is. In simple terms, you can create as many objects of `NewClass` as you want, each with its own different depth value:

```
//one:
NewClass nc1 = new NewClass();
nc1.setDepth(2.3);
System.out.println("The depth of first one is " + nc1.getDepth());

//another:
NewClass nc2 = new NewClass();
nc2.setDepth(488.2);
System.out.println("The depth of second one is " + nc2.getDepth());
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is your class:**

```
   public class NewClass {
      private double depth;
      public NewClass(){

      public double getDepth() {
          return depth;
      }

     public void setDepth(double d){
         depth = d;
     }
    }
```

**To call the method from other class:**

```
    import NewClass;
    public class MainClass{

        public static void main(String args[]){
           NewClass  newClass = new NewClass();
           Double depth = newClass.getDepth();
           System.out.println("The depth is "+depth);
        }

    }
```

*So, the fundamental is :*
You define new object for the class name and call it's method:

```
 NewClass  newClass = new NewClass();
 newClass.getDepth();
```